# Joomla 3 Component - Upload Image and Convert with Imagick

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-extensions, imagick, joomla3.0

I am currently creating a component, where a user creates a new image and there's an upload button and a name input, all the basic gallery fields for an Image..

But I have come across two issues, the one is how would i write the following code so that it exports one image b/w and the other color scaled to amax width of 160, Here's the code I have:

```
function save(){
    if(!defined('DS')) define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
    $input=JFactory::getApplication()->input;
    $input->get('jform', NULL, NULL);

    $file = JRequest::getVar('jform', null, 'files', 'array');
    $data = JRequest::getVar( 'jform', null, 'post', 'array' );
    $path = JPATH_ROOT;

    //
    //

    // Make the file name safe.
    jimport('joomla.filesystem.file');
    $file['name']['logo'] = JFile::makeSafe($file['name']['logo']);

    // Move the uploaded file into a permanent location.
    if (isset($file['name']['logo'])) {
        // Make sure that the full file path is safe.
        $filepath = JPath::clean($path. DS ."images". DS ."associations". DS . strtolower($file['name']['logo']));
        // Move the uploaded file.
        JFile::upload( $file['tmp_name']['logo'], $filepath );
        $data['logo'] = strtolower( $file['name']['logo'] );
        //convert image
        $image = $filepath;

        $im = new Imagick();
        $im->pingImage($image);
        $im->readImage( $image );

        $im->setImageResolution(72,72);
        $im->resampleImage(72,72,imagick::FILTER_UNDEFINED,1);
        $im->scaleImage(160,0); 

        $im->setImageFormat('jpeg');
        $im->setImageCompression(imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);
        $im->setImageCompressionQuality(60);

        $im->modulateImage(100, 0, 100); 
        $im->writeImage($image);
        $im->destroy();
    }

    $input->post->set('jform',$data);

    return parent::save();
}
```

And Finally, How Would I manage this? it saves the image name in the database but once i return to this item it just has an upload field, where it would be rather useful to have the image name or the actual image with a delete function showing and a reupload...

Am I going the right way about this?... Any Help Greatly Appreciated... Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### How to produce 2 images

You have to create 2 resources out from the uploaded original, transform each and save in the separate file. For example I'be using the [`JImage`](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/tree/master/libraries/joomla/image) package (note there's no limitcolors filter available)

```
$image_one = new JImage($filepath);
$image_one
    ->filter('grayscale')
    ->toFile($path_one, IMAGETYPE_JPEG, array('quality' => 60));

$image_two = new JImage($filePath);
$image_two
    ->filter('limitcolors', array('limit' => 160))
    ->toFile($path_two, IMAGETYPE_GIF);
```

### Managing images

Depends on the reason, why there"s functionality being implemented and so relation of the uploaded image to other objects/ events.

If the uploaded images are used for user profiles, you should store a user id in the database along with image location. Next time check if current users has any images related to his/ her account and display.